# Synapse: Dynamic Switch between Linked Services

Tags: azure-synapse

I have a `Synapse pipeline` in `git repo` and use it in two Synapse workspaces. The pipelines call databricks notebooks (notebook names are identical, only the workspaces are different) and so the only thing that I have to change to run the Synapse pipeline in the second workspace are the used linked services. So currently I make a git pull in the second Synapse workspace and change the linked serves manually.

I am aware of the [Parameterize linked services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/parameterize-linked-services?tabs=data-factory) which help to set parameters within a linked service but I have to do something like a dynamic linked service lookup.